# Java netbeans how to make a gui run at starting in the jar file

Tags: java, netbeans-8

So I have made a new Application in Java Netbeans. I made the "Main UI" of the application in my first JFrame Form. Then I started making another JFrame "Login UI". Now I want the "Login UI" to run first in my jar file. But by default it is running the first "Main UI". I just simply want to run My second UI "Login UI" first.

Comment: The thing is that if you wouldn't use 2 JFrames you would probably have no problem now. Having to handle 2 JFrames is not so good practice. You could use JDialogs instead. Or a JFrame that its content pane changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Login UI java file and press Shift+F6. That command will run the file that is open if it has a `main` method.

P.S: To permanently make that class the project's main class, right click the project, select Properties, select Run on the left, and change the Main Class option.

Comment: I have done that to run and test my application, What I want is to make it run first in my .jar file.

Comment: I've added to the answer.